# How to put condition equal to two strings

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am working on an ATM college project.

When a user enters his password in a textbox, the password is saved in the database.

I want to compare the password entered in a textbox with the password saved in database. I am getting the password from database but cannot put an equal statement.

The code is as follows:

```cs
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (rdr.Read())
{
    string cus_pin = rdr["pin"].ToString();
    string cus_pin_byuser = textBox1.ToString();

    if (string.Equals(cus_pin, cus_pin_byuser) == true)
    {
        cust_main cm = new cust_main();
        cm.label1.Text = label7.Text;
        cm.label2.Text = label6.Text;
        cm.label4.Text = label8.Text;

        CodeVer codeVer = new CodeVer();

        codeVer.getUserAccountNumber(name);
        codeVer.Show();

        this.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Pin");
    }
}
```

Comment: Not clear what the issue is.  Use the debugger to step through the lines to examine the values.  In the real world, you would never store a password in the database.

Comment: Aside from best practices regarding passwords, one issue is that the Equals method would be used like so: `cus_pin.Equals(cus_pin_byuser)`, another being you would get the text from the text box using `textBox1.Text`, since ToString would give you the `TextBox` fully qualified class name

Comment: LarsTech.i have debugged it it shows the values but equal statement donot worked

Comment: If you did, then you would have seen that `textBox1.ToString()` does not return what you think it returns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might be applying .ToString() on the textBox object. I suppose you want to use textBox1.Text.

So the code would become:

```
...
string cus_pin = rdr["pin"].ToString()
string cus_pin_byuser = textBox1.Text; 

if (cus_pin == cus_pin_byuser)
...
```

Also, please note that it is really insecure to store the user's password as plain text. Please store it's hashed version. I really recommend reading on the [OWASP's password storage cheat sheet.](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.md)

Comment: The ToString should stay on the `rdr["pin"]` line.

Comment: @AhmArKAka Great!